# Extract part of string values, make new column names, and make dataframe wide

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I want to extract the last part of a string column (always wrapped in square brackets), make these the names of new columns, and then reshape the data from long to wide and fill the new columns with these values.

For example, if I have this dataframe:

```
whatihave <- data_frame(v1 = c('abc [effort]', 'def [effort]', 'ghi [effort]', 'abc [scope]', 'def [scope]', 'ghi [scope]'),
                        scores = c(1:6))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  v1           scores
  <chr>         <int>
1 abc [effort]      1
2 def [effort]      2
3 ghi [effort]      3
4 abc [scope]       4
5 def [scope]       5
6 ghi [scope]       6
```

I want to transform it into this dataframe:

```
whatiwant <- data_frame(v1 = c('abc', 'def', 'ghi'), 
                        effort = c(1, 2, 3),
                        scope = c(4, 5, 6))

  v1    effort scope
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 abc        1     4
2 def        2     5
3 ghi        3     6
```

As you can see, the characters inside the square brackets at the end of the values in the `v1` column have become the names of two new variables (`effort` and `scope`). The values from the `scores` column have then filled the new columns i've made.

How do I do this?

**EDIT BELOW**

The toy data I mocked up was missing a key feature of my actual data. There are actually multiple instances of the same v1 value and with the same suffix in square brackets.

As a result the answer below (which is otherwise excellent) results in lists of cols in each cell of `effort` and `scope` instead of individual values.

Let's imagine I have this data instead:

```
whatiactuallyhave <- data_frame(v1 = c('abc [effort]', 'abc [effort]', 'def [effort]', 'def [effort]', 'ghi [effort]', 'abc [scope]', 'abc [scope]', 'def [scope]', 'ghi [scope]', 'ghi [scope]'), 
                        scores = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   v1           scores
   <chr>        <chr> 
 1 abc [effort] 1     
 2 abc [effort] 2     
 3 def [effort] 3     
 4 def [effort] 4     
 5 ghi [effort] 5     
 6 abc [scope]  6     
 7 abc [scope]  7     
 8 def [scope]  8     
 9 ghi [scope]  9     
10 ghi [scope]  10
```

And that I want to transform it to this:

```
whatiactuallywant <- data_frame(v1 = c('abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def', 'ghi', 'ghi'), 
                        effort = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'NA'),
                        scope = c('6', '7', '8', 'NA', '9', '10'))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  v1    effort scope
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 abc   1      6    
2 abc   2      7    
3 def   3      8    
4 def   4      NA   
5 ghi   5      9    
6 ghi   NA     10
```

I hope that's clearer now! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Revised scenario

- Using `tidyr::extract` will lead you saving one extra step of mutate as you can directly extract two desired strings into two columns using `regex` here.

```r
library(tidyverse)
whatiactuallyhave <- data_frame(v1 = c('abc [effort]', 'abc [effort]', 'def [effort]', 'def [effort]', 'ghi [effort]', 'abc [scope]', 'abc [scope]', 'def [scope]', 'ghi [scope]', 'ghi [scope]'), 
                                scores = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'))
#> Warning: `data_frame()` was deprecated in tibble 1.1.0.
#> Please use `tibble()` instead.

whatiactuallyhave %>%
  tidyr::extract(v1, into = c('v1', 'name'), regex = '(\\w+)\\s\\[(\\w+)\\]') %>%
  group_by(v1, name) %>%
  mutate(d = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = scores, values_fill = NA) %>%
  select(-d)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   v1 [3]
#>   v1    effort scope
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 abc   1      6    
#> 2 abc   2      7    
#> 3 def   3      8    
#> 4 def   4      <NA> 
#> 5 ghi   5      9    
#> 6 ghi   <NA>   10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

#### Earlier answer

```
whatihave <- data_frame(v1 = c('abc [effort]', 'def [effort]', 'ghi [effort]', 'abc [scope]', 'def [scope]', 'ghi [scope]'),
                        scores = c(1:6))

library(tidyverse)
whatihave %>%
  separate(v1, into = c('v1', 'name'), sep = ' \\[') %>%
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, '\\]')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = scores)


# A tibble: 3 x 3
  v1    effort scope
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 abc        1     4
2 def        2     5
3 ghi        3     6
```

Comment: It wasn't me! I thought it was great -- was about to accept as the answer but realized that the toy data I mocked up is missing a crucial feature -- am about to edit OP now to clarify

Comment: @C.Robin, see revised answer, please

Comment: This perfectly solves my question Anil. Thanks! In my actual data the `v1` column is actually a much longer string, with multiple spaces and words, etc., but it always ends with the square brackets containing either 'effort' or 'scope'. So, for example it could contain the value: "`this is just a really long strong, for example: maybe a survey question? [effort]`". What would the regex be for that?

Answer (score 2):

This solution is very similar to the one posted by my dear friend @AnilGoyal, as only the regex is different:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stingr)
library(tidyr)

whatiactuallyhave %>% 
  extract(v1, c("v1", "v2"), "([a-z]+) ([[a-z]+])") %>%
  mutate(v2 = str_replace(v2, "\\[(\\w+)\\]", "\\1")) %>%
  group_by(v1, v2) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = v2, values_from = scores) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   v1 [3]
  v1    effort scope
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 abc   1      6    
2 abc   2      7    
3 def   3      8    
4 def   4      NA   
5 ghi   5      9    
6 ghi   NA     10
```