# Extract everything up to a "]" character in a string

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I want to extract two parts of a string variable, and turn it into two new variables.

Say I have this dataframe:

```
df2 <- data.frame(question = c('I am a long question / am i? [type]', 'I am a long question / am i? [form]', 'Short question; i guess? [type]', 'Short question; i guess? [form]', 'Roiled and rumbled, so said the toad... [type]', 'Roiled and rumbled, so said the toad... [form]'),
                 values = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

                                        question values
1            I am a long question / am i? [type]      1
2            I am a long question / am i? [form]      2
3                Short question; i guess? [type]      3
4                Short question; i guess? [form]      4
5 Roiled and rumbled, so said the toad... [type]      5
6 Roiled and rumbled, so said the toad... [form]      6
```

I want to transform the `question` variable so everything on the left of the square brackets is in one column and everything inside the square brackets is in another column (i do not need to keep the original `question` variable).

So basically i want this:

```
                                        question   v2  values
1                   I am a long question / am i?   type     1
2                   I am a long question / am i?   form     2
3                       Short question; i guess?   type     3
4                       Short question; i guess?   form     4
5        Roiled and rumbled, so said the toad...   type     5
6        Roiled and rumbled, so said the toad...   form     6
```

Currently i have this code, which doesn't quite work:

```
df2 %>% tidyr::extract(question, into = c('question', 'v2'), regex = '(\\w+)\\s\\[(\\w+)\\]')
```

Comment: Just replace `(\\w+)` as a first capture group to `(.*)` and it'll work.  In your previous question, your first capture group was a single word only and that's why I [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67708075/2884859) this regex. `df2 %>% tidyr::extract(question, into = c('question', 'v2'), regex = '(.*)\\s\\[(\\w+)\\]')`

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks Anil. It felt like a substantially different part of the question so made sense to me to make a new post (also in terms of breaking out the parts of the problem for others)

Comment: Its OK.  Actually `\\w` will not be able to capture non-word characters!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. Extract everything until square brackets -

```
tidyr::extract(df2, question, into = c('question', 'v2'), 
                regex = '(.*)\\s\\[(\\w+)\\]')

#.                                question   v2 values
#1            I am a long question / am i? type      1
#2            I am a long question / am i? form      2
#3                Short question; i guess? type      3
#4                Short question; i guess? form      4
#5 Roiled and rumbled, so said the toad... type      5
#6 Roiled and rumbled, so said the toad... form      6
```

The same regex can also be used in `strcapture` to do it in base R -

```
cbind(strcapture('(.*)\\s\\[(\\w+)\\]', df2$question, 
      proto = list(question = character(), v2 = character())), df2[2])
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! This is exactly what I needed