# Piping df into mutate + substring expression

Tags: r, dplyr

**Context:** Say I have this `df`:

```
df <- tibble(v1 = c('abc [effort]', 'abc [effort]', 'def [effort]', 'def [effort]', 'ghi [effort]', 'abc [scope]', 'abc [scope]', 'def [scope]', 'ghi [scope]', 'ghi [scope]'), 
             v2 = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'))

> df
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   v1           v2   
   <chr>        <chr>
 1 abc [effort] 1    
 2 abc [effort] 2    
 3 def [effort] 3    
 4 def [effort] 4    
 5 ghi [effort] 5    
 6 abc [scope]  6    
 7 abc [scope]  7    
 8 def [scope]  8    
 9 ghi [scope]  9    
10 ghi [scope]  10
```

and I want to extract everything left of the square brackets in the string `v1` and put it into a new variable called `lhs`. I could use `tidyr::extract` and the correct regular expression (as others have pointed out [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719213/extract-everything-up-to-a-character-in-a-string)). And if I want to use `stringr` notation, I can extract the text as needed like so:

```
str_sub(df$v1, 1, str_locate(df$v1, pattern = "\\[")-1)
```

**Problem 1:** But if I try and assign this to `df` I get an error:

```
> df$lhs <- str_sub(df$v1, 1, str_locate(df$v1, pattern = "\\[")-1)

Error: Assigned data `str_sub(...)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 10 rows.
x Assigned data has 20 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**Problem 2:** Similarly, it feels like it should be possible to implement this using piping notation from `dplyr` but that also returns an error:

```
df %>% str_sub(v1, 1, str_locate(v1, pattern = "\\[")-1)

Error in str_sub(., v1, 1, str_locate(v1, pattern = "\\[") - 1) : 
  unused argument (str_locate(v1, pattern = "\\[") - 1)
```

**Problem 3:** And finally, i'd think that I could integrate the substringing with `mutate`, but that returns an error as well:

```
df %>% mutate(lhs = str_sub(v1, 1, str_locate(df$v1, pattern = "\\[")-1))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `question`.
x Input `question` can't be recycled to size 10.
ℹ Input `question` is `str_sub(v1, 1, str_locate(df$v1, pattern = "\\[") - 1)`.
ℹ Input `question` must be size 10 or 1, not 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Forgive the noob question here, but i'm trying to understand why `stringr` doesn't seem to play nicely with other `tidyverse` functions. Feels counterintuitive to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `str_locate` is a `matrix` of 'start', 'end', columns.

```
str_locate(df$v1, pattern = "\\[")-1
      start end
 [1,]     4   4
 [2,]     4   4
 [3,]     4   4
 [4,]     4   4
 [5,]     4   4
 [6,]     4   4
 [7,]     4   4
 [8,]     4   4
 [9,]     4   4
[10,]     4   4
```

we need to extract one of them, it is not clear which one the OP wanted.  If we need the 'start' column, use either index of names.  The issue in OP's code is that the output was replicated twice and this triggered the length difference error

```
df$lhs <- str_sub(df$v1, 1, str_locate(df$v1, pattern = "\\[")[,1] -1)
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   v1           v2    lhs   
   <chr>        <chr> <chr> 
 1 abc [effort] 1     "abc "
 2 abc [effort] 2     "abc "
 3 def [effort] 3     "def "
 4 def [effort] 4     "def "
 5 ghi [effort] 5     "ghi "
 6 abc [scope]  6     "abc "
 7 abc [scope]  7     "abc "
 8 def [scope]  8     "def "
 9 ghi [scope]  9     "ghi "
10 ghi [scope]  10    "ghi "
```

---

Regarding the OP's usage of

```
df %>%
    str_sub(v1, 1, str_locate(v1, pattern = "\\[")-1)
```

The data coming from the lhs of %>% is the whole data and we need to extract the column 'v1'

```
df %>%
  { str_sub(.$v1, 1, str_locate(.$v1, pattern = "\\[")[,1]-1)}
```

Or use `with`

```
df %>%
   with(.,  str_sub(v1, 1, str_locate(v1, pattern = "\\[")[,1]-1))
```

Or this can also be done with `|>` (base R `R 4.1.0`)

```
df |>
  {\(x) str_sub(x$v1, 1, str_locate(x$v1, pattern = "\\[")[,1]-1)}()
 #[1] "abc " "abc " "def " "def " "ghi " "abc " "abc " "def " "ghi " "ghi "
```

---

Or another option is to use `str_remove`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(v1 = str_remove(v1, "\\s+.*"))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do this easily with `read.table`

```
read.table(text = df$v1, sep=" ", header = FALSE)[,1]
#[1] "abc" "abc" "def" "def" "ghi" "abc" "abc" "def" "ghi" "ghi"
```

Comment: This is great Akrun. Indicating which column (`start` or `end`) I want from the substring expression solves problem 1 from my question, but doesn't explain why this wouldn't work, for example: `df %>% str_sub(v1, 1, str_locate(v1, pattern = "\\[")[,1]-1)`

Comment: @C.Robin You are not extracting the column 'v1'.  You may need `df %>% pull(v1) %>% {str_sub(., 1, str_locate(., ..`.  There is a reason it works inside the tidyverse functions like mutate/summarise etc as it will be evaluated as a vector

Comment: I really appreciate your reply! Definitely valuable from my perspective (not sure what you mean by 'won't be any value'...)! I still don't understand why piping the `df` into the `str_sub()` function doesn't work but you've helped me understand part of the problem

Comment: @C.Robin As I said the syntax for using `tidyverse` is that `v1` when you are placing outside the tidyverse functions is not recognised as the  data coming the rhs of %>% is the whole data and not the v1.  You may need `.$v1 %>% str_sub(..`

Comment: Ok thanks -- that's a bit clearer. I'm going to have to mull on this and play around with some examples to really 'get' it though. Thanks again for your reply! Really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use separate.  To keep the original column add the remove=FALSE argument. If you don't want the B column use c("A", NA) as the second argument.

```
df %>% separate(v1, c("A", "B"), extra = "drop")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   A     B      v2   
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>
 1 abc   effort 1    
 2 abc   effort 2    
 3 def   effort 3    
 4 def   effort 4    
 5 ghi   effort 5    
 6 abc   scope  6    
 7 abc   scope  7    
 8 def   scope  8    
 9 ghi   scope  9    
10 ghi   scope  10
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- this is a nice approach. I think there are lots of ways to solve the problem in the use case I presented; my specific question is about why piping the df into mutate didn't work though

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `stringr::strsplit()`, and then use `sapply()` to get the first element of each.

```
df %>% mutate( lhs = sapply(strsplit(df$v1, " \\["),`[`, 1))
```